# Write a C program to find a root of $x^3 - 3*x + 1 = 0$ by fixed point iteration method (including convergence check)

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

The code works fine. But I want to include the convergence criterion which is as follows:

if the equation is written in the form $x=g(x)$, then condition of convergence is: $g'(x)<1$.

Note that:  $g(x)=\sqrt [3]{3\,x-1}$ and $g'(x)=\left( 3\,x-1 \right) ^{-2/3}$

Please modify my code for convergence.

```
  /* g (x) = (3x - l)^(l/3 ), x0=5 */
/* Fixed po int of Iteration Method */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
float g(float x)
{
return(pow((3*x-1), (.3333 )));
}

void main()
{
int n, i ;
float x0 ,xl ;
clrscr() ;
printf ("Enter xO , n");
scanf ("%f%d" ,&x0,&n);
for (i= 1;i<=n;i++ )
{

xl=g(x0);
printf("\t\t i=%d \t\t x1=%f\n\n", i,xl);
if(fabs (xl-x0)<.0001)
break ;
else
x0=xl;
}
printf ("The root is %£ ", xl);
getch();
}
```

Comment: What's your question then?

Comment: @caverac code for convergence

Comment: 1) Have you found $g$? 2) Can you differentiate $g$?

Comment: @mathreadler $g(x)=\sqrt [3]{3\,x-1}$ and $g'(x)=\left( 3\,x-1 \right) ^{-2/3}$

Comment: yep, and you see how $g$ is implemented in the code, I presume. how can you copy the code for $g$ and modify it to do $g'$?

Comment: float gd(float x)
{
return(pow((3*x-1), (-2/3.0 )));
}

Comment: Yes, that is quite close, but would be a bit better with 3.0 and 2.0 because c interprets numbers without dots to be integers. The dot makes them double precision floats (double) and if you add "f" on end they will be single precision floats (float) like so: 3.0f and 2.0f. But this all is quite out of scope of the math.stackexchange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88574/discussion-between-user1942348-and-mathreadler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned the code a bit, and used another function $g(x) = (x^3 + 1)/3$ and $g'(x) = x^2$. So as long as you start in $|x|<1$ convergence will work

```
/* g (x) = (3x - l)^(l/3 ), x0=5 */
/* Fixed po int of Iteration Method */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float g(float x)
{
  return (x * x * x + 1) / 3.;
}

float dg(float x)
{
  return x * x;
}

int main()
{
  int n, i;
  float x0, xl, d;
  char convergence;
  printf ("Enter x0, n: ");
  scanf ("%f %d", &x0, &n);

  for (i = 1; i <= n; i ++)
  {
    xl = g(x0);
    d = dg(x0);
    convergence = fabs(d) < 1 ? 't' : 'f';

    printf("\t\t i = %d \t\t x1 = %f \t\t g'(x1) = %f \t\t convergence = %c\n", i, xl, d, convergence);
    if(fabs (xl - x0) < .0001)
      break;
    else
      x0 = xl;
  }

  printf ("The root is %f\n", xl);
}
```

This is a test

```
Enter x0, n: 0.1 10
         i = 1       x1 = 0.333667       g'(x1) = 0.010000       convergence = t
         i = 2       x1 = 0.345716       g'(x1) = 0.111333       convergence = t
         i = 3       x1 = 0.347107       g'(x1) = 0.119520       convergence = t
         i = 4       x1 = 0.347273       g'(x1) = 0.120483       convergence = t
         i = 5       x1 = 0.347294       g'(x1) = 0.120599       convergence = t
The root is 0.347294
```

Comment: Thank you. Please explain the line "convergence = fabs(d) < 1 ? 't' : 'f';" Also, if g'(x1) >=1, please, I want to get a message of non-convergence

Comment: @user1942348 That is short for `if (fabs(d)) < 1 then convergence = true, else convergence = false`. You can modify that bit at your convenience

Comment: This code works good for |x|<1 only

Comment: There is a root 1.5319 also. How to catch that root

Comment: @user1942348 You can manipulate the function $g$ to ensure convergence. For example $g(x) = (3x - 1)^{1/3}$ has $g'(1.53) < 1$, so you could try that version of $g$ instead